# Making calls to 3rd party service testable

Tags: ruby

I want to know if this is a good strategy for avoiding calls to 3rd party services in my tests.

I have 2 classes that encapsulate calls to 3rd party services that I call PersonIdentifier and FIleManager.

In order to make these classes testable, I pass them into the constructor of another class like this:

```
CreateContact.new(current_user, input, PersonIdentifier.new, FileManager.new)
```

But the creation of this CreateContact instance might be in a class method or instance method.  So in the case of a class method, I create another class method that creates the instance, e.g.

```
  def self.create_contact(current_user, input)
    CreateContact.new(current_user, input, PersonIdentifier.new, FileManager.new)
  end
```

Then in my tests, I use instance_eval to override this method, e.g.

```
  def setup
    super

    EmailIdentifier.instance_eval do
      def create_contact(current_user, input)
        CreateContact.new(current_user, input, TestPersonIdentifier.new, TestFileManager.new)
      end
    end
  end
```

It is a bit of a pain to add more than one class_eval or instance_eval in my test setups.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your code, the dependency is too strong.

```
def self.create_contact(current_user, input)
  CreateContact.new(current_user, input, PersonIdentifier.new, FileManager.new)
end
```

You called two external objects implicitly in code.

I will refactor the code at first to allow dependency injection

```
def self.create_contact(user, input, person_identifier=nil, file_manager=nil)
  # current_user seems very specific, replaced by a general name 'user'
  person_identifier ||= PersonIdentifier.new
  file_manager      ||= FilerManager.new
  new(user, input, person_identifier, file_manager)
end
```

By this way, any instance can be injected into this method, you've removed dependency from these two classes.

Then, in test, what your need to is to simply mock these two instance. I'm familiar with Rspec only so can't provide specific code, but the principle is the same.